# Omniauth & Foursquare: uid is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, foursquare

I'm using the last omniauth gem, and the omniauth-foursquare gem `gem 'omniauth-foursquare'`.

When I try to login via foursquare, the callback returns:

```
#<OmniAuth::AuthHash ... provider="foursquare" redirect_uri="blabla" uid=nil>
```

uid is nil :(

I'm also using `omniauth-contrib` for twitter, and `omniauth-facebook` for... facebook. These work fine, I get a valid uid.

Do you think it's the gem? Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the gem.  It's missing the uid block.  It's fixed in the code here: https://github.com/brendte/omniauth-foursquare.  It also adds the raw data returned by foursquare to the extra hash.

Comment: Released a new version. Please give a try now. Thanks Brendten

Answer (score 1):

Released a newer version https://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-foursquare/versions/0.0.4

You can use :-)